# Why after command git branch I see origin/master instead of master

Tags: git, branch

my mate tried to clone sources from git branch.
When I tried on his machine "git branch", it outputs: origin/master.
I have cloned the same sources but after git branch I saw always output: master.
I read that origin/master means remote branch and I don't understand why he sees remote branch instead of local branch.
What can be reason of problem ?

Comment: Can you provide results of `git config --global -l` and `git config --system -l` and `git config --local -l ` The last one from within the repo dir. (You can ofcourse anonymize any email and other sensitive data)

Answer (score 2):

I think an answer is quite simple, your friend checked out to an origin/master insted of master.
Execute cmd:

```
git branch --all
```

In list of shown branches try to find branch `master`, and if no such branch, just checkout to it

```
git checkout master
```

And then delete origin/master from local copies

```
git branch -D origin/master
```

Comment: Can you please help me understand what is the difference between cloning from master and cloning from origin/master ? I don't understand it because in both cases I must clone from remote branch and origin/master means remote branch so why is there difference ?

Comment: When you are cloning a project you are getting two things **master** and **origin/master** branches. **origin/master** - responsible for contain remote changes. **master** - responsible for contain local changes

Comment: To synchronize changes in-between **master** and **origin/master** branches you can do two things: 
1) git pull (which is alias under `git fetch` and `git merge origin/master` commands)
2) or you can do it manually  `git fetch` and `git merge origin/master`

Comment: But origin/master exists just for view/apply remote changes, but not for development! For development you should use only **master** branch

Comment: Thanks Yuriy for clean explanation. It is clean for me now.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by the disambiguation of references as it is possible to name a local branch origin/master.

See [Git Revisions Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#revisions-ltrefnamegtegmasterheadsmasterrefsheadsmaster) for details, but to summarize, when resolving a reference it checks the following locations in sequence and returns the first match:

```
$GIT_DIR/<refname>
$GIT_DIR/refs/<refname>
$GIT_DIR/refs/tags/<refname>
$GIT_DIR/refs/heads/<refname>
$GIT_DIR/refs/remotes/<refname>
$GIT_DIR/refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD
```

Look in your friend's repository and you'll find this file 
`$GIT_DIR/refs/heads/origin/master`. If so, everything is working correctly and he's just got an ambiguous reference. He'll want to change his local branch name to remove the ambiguity so there are no unexpected issues from the disambiguation.

This usually occurs on checkout when you type `git checkout -b origin/master` instead of `git checkout -b master origin/master`

As a side note, your local branch name is just a pointer to a commit, so it doesn't really matter what it's named (as long as it's not ambiguous). When pushing to a remote, you update the remote's branch based on the local branch's remote settings, so your local branch name will never be seen by anyone else.